# LibGdx: Pad the text inside an ImageTextButton

Tags: libgdx

How can I pad (move around) text inside an `ImageTextButton`? Getting the cell of the label seems to not do anything.

```
ImageTextButton btn= new ImageTextButton("some text", btnStyle);
btn.getLabelCell().padLeft(-200); //does nothing
```